# Safari isn't playing video, how to play aal browser play video?

Tags: css, html, video, web

Safari  isn't playing video, Youtube and mp4 videos do not play on my site [creativecartels.biz](http://creativecartels.biz/demo/forget-reg/index.html). Code below:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 pad-left">
    <div class="videoWrapper">
      <div class="bggg" id="uni_bggg"><img src="images/video-mage.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="video-paly-button" id="uni_video_paly_button">
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('video-bg').play();document.getElementById('uni_video_paly_button').remove();document.getElementById('uni_bggg').remove();"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
      </div>
      <video controls id="video-bg">
        <source src="images/Forget reg Tv Ad long.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
        Your browser does not support the video tag</video>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Safari with windows os will support only mov video format. It will not support any other video format. Try to check in mac  it will play the video.